# Does /kill @e target Item Frames and Armor Stands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In one world I tried to fight nine stacks of zombies at once, but it lagged my pc out and I had to use `/kill @e` to get everything back in order. On the same map, I had a 341 map megamap that was on item frames, and they were destroyed.

Does /kill @e target Item Frames and Armor Stands too?

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797)

Comment: Yes! Minecart affect too

Comment: If you press `f3+b` it will show the hitbox of things around you. Anything that has hitbox is considered an entity, thus killing it with `/kill @e`. Also you can do `/kill @e[type=X]` to kill a certai type, such as players, villagers, zombies, or anything really.

Comment: What does “9 stack of zombies” mean

Answer (score 0):

The 'e' in '@e' stands for entities, so in that case, maybe Armor Stands and Item Frames are considered entities too? If i'm correct, there is a Minecraft Gamepedia Wiki page telling all about 'Entities'. Maybe use that to discover every single entity and mob that can be defeated using this command. I hope it works...https://minecraft.wiki/w/Entity

Answer (score 0):

Yes, item frames and armor stands are entities. The same goes for paintings.

If you want to not destroy item frames and armor stands when using /kill @e, run this command:

```
/kill @e[type=!item_frame,type=!armor_stand]
```

I hope this helps. ;D